# To trust someone as far as you can throw them

Tags: etymology, idioms

Does anybody know the source of this idiom or have an explanation of how it originated? I know it means that the speaker does not trust the person in question, but I want to know the etymology of the idiom. How did it mutate from something literal into this? Obviously trust is not measured in the same way as distance, so I want to understand the correlation in this context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't offer an authoritive source. However there is another expression, 'I can't trust him out of my sight' that makes the meaning obvious.

Most children go through a stage where their parents must keep a careful eye on them to prevent the child getting up to mischief. The parent might say, "Now he is a toddler, I can't trust him of out of my sight. He is always poking his fingers into everything and I'm worried he may electrocute himself or pull the bookshelves on top of him."  This literally means that the parent is happy only when they can see the child.

When you can trust someone as far as you can throw them, it is just an exaggerated form of the previous expression. It means we can trust them at zero distance, i.e. not at all. We usually say this about adults and of course most people cannot throw another adult any distance at all.

EDIT

I've found some more evidence as to how the phrase may have developed.

> If you haven't got any confidence in a man, you can't say much worse
>   of him than this — ' I'll trust him as far as I can see.'
>
> [The City Road Magazine 1874](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=H_gDAAAAQAAJ&q=%22trust%20him%20as%20far%20as%22&dq=%22trust%20him%20as%20far%20as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAmoVChMInvOix8_yxwIVpaDbCh1JlAto)

---

> Ye cain't trust him as far as ye kin throw a b'ar. That's why we call
>   him Snake.
>
> [Boys' Life - Aug 1930 - Page 22](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=secyNQckEqMC&pg=PA22&dq=%22trust%20him%20as%20far%20as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBGoVChMInvOix8_yxwIVpaDbCh1JlAto#v=onepage&q=%22trust%20him%20as%20far%20as%22&f=false)

---

> I know all about Otto Ernsthausen. I wouldn't trust him as far as I
>   can spit!
>
> [Big Show By Charles Cooke - Harper & brothers, 1938 - 358 pages](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Z1FCAAAAIAAJ&q=%22trust%20him%20as%20far%20as%22&dq=%22trust%20him%20as%20far%20as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAmoVChMIuu704dDyxwIVw67bCh28rgK4)

P.S.

However [A Dictionary of Catch Phrases By Eric Partridge](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YcWHAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA227&dq=trust%20him%20as%20far%20as%20I%20can%20throw%201930&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAGoVChMIv4PK0dPyxwIVZoLbCh1v2gDf#v=onepage&q=trust%20him%20as%20far%20as%20I%20can%20throw%201930&f=false) traces it back to 1870.

P.P.S.  I think I've beaten Eric Partridge with this !

*Somethin furthur,' siz I, ' than I'd trust you.' 'How far is that?' siz he. “Just as far, then, siz I, as I could throw a bull by the tail.* [The Westminster Review - Volume 9 - Page 434 -  **1828**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eoBFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA434&dq=you%20can%27t%20trust%20them%20as%20far%20as%20you%20can%20throw%20a%20bull%20by%20the%20tail.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMIyPi44ejyxwIVxWbbCh1ueAYF#v=onepage&q=you%20can't%20trust%20them%20as%20far%20as%20you%20can%20throw%20a%20bull%20by%20the%20tail.&f=false)

Comment: Actually, in the case of my question, I'm dealing with a form of the idiom where one says it without the negative contraction (i.e. "can't" or "don't").

Also, I don't think it mutated in the way you're saying (by exaggerating the expression applied to toddlers), as the use case is different (one applies to toddlers that don't know better, and the other typically applies to adults that at least have a good idea of the consequences of their actions.) You typically throw an enemy; you don't throw a toddler

Comment: @TwistedCode - You are right, it's not normally negative and I've edited to remove that. However it doesn't change my reasoning.  As I said, it refers to throwing an adult and the distance most people can throw an adult is zero or at most a few feet.

Comment: You sure you actually save your edit? It doesn't seem to show when I check your revision history, and I refreshed the page and it still appears to be negated. (If you don't know what happened, blame Microcrap Windoze (regardless of if you're using it). That's my typical scapegoat when dealing with computers)

Comment: I was commenting and editing at the same time and forgot to save the edit! Should be okay now.

Comment: Okay, now it shows, but I think the post still needs a bit of tweaking. Mind if I give it a shot?

Comment: I've added some more examples. I haven't done the research for when the precise phrase was invented but variants have been around for some time. If you want to track it down more precisely then I suggest searching Google Books or Google ngram.

Comment: In "The Free-thinker" - From Lady-day to Michaelmas Vol 1 (1718), you find in page 137 the following sentence: *In the next place, our old Cautious English Proverb allow us to "Trust every man so far as we can see him"*.

Comment: I've just found this ---> The Reasoner, Volume 19  - **1855** ---> *Trust a priest as far as you can throw him, but no farther.*   https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TuA6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA190&dq=trust+%22far+as%22++%22can+throw+him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI_fCPhODyxwIVhmrbCh2gvAnr#v=onepage&q=trust%20%22far%20as%22%20%20%22can%20throw%20him%22&f=false

Comment: Good research. Another early instance of the expression "trust [one] as far as [the speaker] can see [one]" appears in _Punch_ (August 11, 1860), in "[John Bull's Answer [to 'The Imperial Billet-Doux'](https://books.google.com/books?id=RDVXAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA57&dq=%22trust+you+as+far%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAGoVChMIme7U7ubyxwIVVpyICh36EgNd#v=onepage&q=%22trust%20you%20as%20far%22&f=false)]": "Volunteers and Defences you think quite disgusting,/As implying mistrust of _your_ word—All my eye!/I'll trust you as far as I see you; so trusting,/You'll excuse me for keping my cartridges dry."

Comment: Don't forget that the original question is about throwing stuff. I've just added to my answer. I've now got the bull's tail one as far back as 1828!

Comment: Chasly's '...as far as I could throw a bull by the tail.' from 'National Tales of Ireland' in the Westminster Review of 1828 ticks all the  boxes.  If we accept that the saying has deep roots then an association with rural life makes sense.  Throwing a bull down by its tail in the days before cattle 'crushes' was the safest way to handle the task.  Since the practice left the animal at the feet of the cattle wrangler it a perfect metaphor for throwing an animal 'no distance at all'.  A lively account is included in Jack Drake's 'The Outback Vs The Wild West', see: http://tinyurl.com/nu5nuu4.

Answer (score 3):

Its origin appears to be obscure as suggested by the Phrase Finder, (also the use of the initial negation is a matter of debate):

[Not trust someone as far as one can throw them](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/not-trust-someone-as-far-as-one-can-throw-them):

> - (informal) Not trust or hardly trust a particular person at all.
>
>   - I would not trust that guy as far as I can throw him, and well, I am small and not strong- so I hope that makes my point.* (ODO)

[Origin](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/51/messages/444.html) of "trust him as far as I can throw him":

> - It's an answer to the question, "How far do you trust this fellow?" Answer: "I trust him as far as I can throw him." Since even a strong man can scarcely throw another full-grown man any further than straight down, the answer is tantamount to "I don't trust him at all.
> - ***" Who first said this? I imagine that that is lost in the mists of time--but not very much time, as I imagine the expression is not much more than a century old, if that.***
> - If you search the expression in Google, you will discover something very odd. A large proportion of those using the expression use it incorrectly, as "I DON'T trust him as far as I can throw him," thus depriving the sentence both of meaning and of the sardonic wit that inspired it.

Comment: We may also imagine that "into the fire" or "into the sea" is omitted after "throw them". By the way, the usual Ottoman punishment for adulterous women was to bind them into a sack and throw them into the sea. So a man can trust his wife as long as he may punish her. Even if such origin prove to be wrong, I like this story too good to be true.

Answer (score 3):

In Nicholas Nickleby (Chapter 17, pg 210), published 1838/1839, Charles Dickens describes Mrs. Knag as one of a [class of people] "described by the axiom, that *you can trust them as far as you can see them*, and no farther."   Hence, it seems that this predates the 1874 reference to the City Road Magazine by 35 years!