# Alternative to "can't trust him farther than I can throw him"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm hoping to find a more colorful version of "which members of the Board are not to be trusted farther than you can throw them."

So far I've found one: "not to be trusted farther than you can spit."

"Spit" is a little yucky for me, for personal reasons, which I'd rather not get into.

Can someone provide another alternative?

Comment: Note that the expression usually is worded: "**as far as**" instead of "farther than".

Comment: ... the point being that you can't throw someone very far, and would not trust him even that much.

Comment: @WeatherVane - So you're saying it would be "which members of the Board are not to be trusted as far as you can throw them"?  I think that does work a bit better.

Comment: @WeatherVane - right trusting someone about as far as you can spit puts more trust in them than trusting someone about as far as you can throw them.

Comment: “*as far as I can throw them*” seems pretty colorful already.  What makes it not colorful enough for your use?

Comment: I believe the (corrected) phrase in the question means you don't trust someone *at all*. I like its colour: the hint of violence if betrayed. The alternative using *spit* also infers disrespect, but suggests there is room for *some* trust.

Comment: Just add as much color as you like:  “I wouldn’t trust those guys as far as I could throw them...  if I were the Venus de Milo”

Comment: @WeatherVane - How about you post your correction as an answer?  The truth is that the reason the phrase wasn't working well was that I was saying it wrong.  I'm going to go ahead and use the corrected phrase in my letter.

Comment: " 'Spit'  s a little yucky for me, for personal reasons, which I'd rather not get into." --- you shouldn't be constructing your article based on idiosyncratic responses you might have to language in it, but instead, based on the responses you are looking to elicit in your readership!

Comment: Hello again @aparente001 and it's good to see you active on EL & U. We need your expert advice (based on your strong background in music) at Interpersonal.SE on an **English language related question from a piano teacher** in the USA teaching a student recently arrived from China, who is yet to learn English. The student's mother is currently acting as an English-Chinese translator but she does not at all understand the musical context, and the teacher-student communication suffers as a result: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/2642/how-do-i-talk-to-someone-through-a-translator

Comment: A related expression to 'wouldn't trust farther than I would throw' is ['wouldn't touch with a bargepole'](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_touch_something_with_a_barge_pole) which mainly connotes aversion, but one reason for such aversion often seems to be *mistrust of the person's credibility*, especially based on an odious track record, as can be seen in some of [these definitions and examples of use.](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=touch+him+with+a+bargepole&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=xeKiWceiMISW8QeX5ZqYCQ)

Comment: @EnglishStudent - I like that.  Worth an answer.

Comment: Thank you, @aparente001 -- now posted with some more detail as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question

> Which members of the Board are not to be trusted farther than you can
>   throw them?

was corrected by @Laurel to the more usual

> Which members of the Board are not to be trusted as far as you can
>   throw them?

the point being that you can't throw someone very far, and would not trust him even *that* much. I believe this phrase means you don't trust someone **at all**. I like its colour: the hint of violence if betrayed.

The alternative question

> Which members of the Board are not to be trusted farther than you can
>   spit?

also implies disrespect, but suggests there is room for some trust.

Comment: I'll just give it until tomorrow before formalizing, but I already upvoted. // I'm baffled by the downvotes on all the answers....

Answer (score 1):

A related expression to 'wouldn't trust farther than I could throw' is 'wouldn't touch with a bargepole' which mainly connotes strong aversion, but one reason for such aversion often seems to be mistrust of the person's credibility, especially based on an odious track record, as can be seen in some of [these definitions and examples of use.](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=touch+him+with+a+bargepole&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=xeKiWceiMISW8QeX5ZqYCQ)

[Macmillan's dictionary online](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bargepole) gives this description in the page defining 'bargepole':

> **I wouldn’t touch it/him/her etc with a bargepole** [British]
>   used for emphasizing that you do not want to be involved with a person or situation, or that you advise someone else not to be involved

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_touch_something_with_a_barge_pole) this expression is

> Probably derived from the barge poles that bargemen used to fend off wharfs and other boats.
>
> **not touch (something) with a barge pole**
>
> (idiomatic, Britain) To avoid something at all costs; to refuse to associate with something; (signifies a strong aversion).
>
> Usage notes: This expression is almost exclusively used in the negative.

A very similar expression is [**'wouldn't touch with a ten foot pole'**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=wouldn%27t+touch+with+a+ten+foot+pole&client=firefox-b&hl=en&sa=X&as_q=&nfpr=&spell=1&ved=0ahUKEwjosqzmrPnVAhXDo48KHbUvBT4QvwUICg) which is apparently a synonym for 'barge pole.'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "not worth their salt" would be a viable alternative.

The expression originates from a Central Asian fealty practice in which a soldier would share salt with a commander they wished to follow (as I remember it, I could be slightly off concerning the derivation) and the phrase, in time, became a moderately common colloquialism.

Example of use: "He isn't worth his salt" = "He can't be trusted"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that works well:

> "Which members of the Board are not to be trusted any further than you
>   can see."

Sourced from [this related discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273736/to-trust-someone-as-far-as-you-can-throw-them) about the etymology of 'To trust someone as far as you can throw them':

> If you haven't got any confidence in a man, you can't say much worse
>   of him than this — ' I'll trust him as far as I can see.'

[The City Road Magazine 1874](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=H_gDAAAAQAAJ&q=%22trust%20him%20as%20far%20as%22&dq=%22trust%20him%20as%20far%20as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAmoVChMInvOix8_yxwIVpaDbCh1JlAto)